# Powerquery iterate over list of steps

Tags: excel, elasticsearch, powerquery

I'm using excel powerquery to pull data from elasticsearch.
It's working fine for one result, but I want to get many. From the initial ES query I get a list of json objects, which I can convert to the table I want quite easily.
The problem is that the query editor only lets me select one result after the other, and not parse everything from the list.

The query is:

```
let

    Content = "{""query"": {""match_all"": {}}}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://es_host:9200/lcm_db/_search"))[hits][hits],
    Source1 = Source{1},
    _source = Source1[_source],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(_source),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table")
in
    #"Transposed Table"

Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://es_host:9200/lcm_db/_search"))[hits][hits]
```

Gives me a list, for which I have to do the 4 steps:

```
Source1 = Source{1},
_source = Source1[_source],
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(_source),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table")
```

How would I make powerquery do those four steps for all the list results?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use List.Transform, and include those 4 steps in a let statement. It would look something like:

```
= List.Transform(Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://es_host:9200/lcm_db/_search"))[hits][hits], (value) => each
    let
        _source = value[_source],
        #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(_source),
        #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table")
    in
        #"Transposed Table")
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the original answer; I've edited it to fix it.